# "Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only" while trying to providing break to x-axis of format "year-week"/"%Y-%W"

Tags: r, ggplot2

The main issue I am working on is to provide breaks in my plot's x-axis.
Now, my x-axis is based on the week of the year in format `YYYY-WW`.

I have tried different ways to do so using ggplot2.

One seems most promising is using the library scales.

But now I am stuck due to the error

> "Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only".

Here is my code snippet :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)
data4 <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\Shailesh\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\4c.csv")


data4 <- melt(data4,  id.vars = c("WEEK.NUMBER", "CURRENT.WEEK.DEATHS", "PREVIOUS.WEEKS.DEATHS"), 
          measure.vars = c("CURRENT.WEEK.DEATHS", "PREVIOUS.WEEKS.DEATHS"))

head(data4)


ggplot(data4, aes(fill=variable, y=value, x=factor(WEEK.NUMBER)), color="black") + 
  geom_bar( stat="identity") +
  labs(x = "Week of Death", y="Number of Deaths") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = '', guide = 'legend',labels = c('Death Reported Previous Week', 'Death Reported Current Week'),
  values = c( "#00ffff","#009933")) +
  #scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 weeks"), labels = date_format("%Y-%W"))+
  theme(legend.position='bottom') + 
  theme( axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size =5))
```

And here is the plot that I am getting by far when I comment out:

```
"scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 weeks"), labels = date_format("%Y-%W"))"
```

[image]

Here is the head of the dataframe after melting:

[image]

How can I resolve this error, how can I give break to the x-axis?

Any will help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a `Date` type field from your *WEEK.NUMBER* and pass that into the *x* of `aes()` call. Also, you should leave out the redundant variables, *CURRENT.WEEK.DEATHS* and *PREVIOUS.WEEKS.DEATHS*, in *id.vars* of `melt`.

```
data4 <- melt(data4, id.vars = c("WEEK.NUMBER"), 
              measure.vars = c("CURRENT.WEEK.DEATHS", "PREVIOUS.WEEKS.DEATHS"))

data4$week_date <- as.Date(paste(data4$WEEK.NUMBER, 1, sep="-"), format="%Y-%W-%w")
```

Alternatively, with `transform`:

```
data4 <- transform(melt(data4, id.vars=c("WEEK.NUMBER"), 
                        measure.vars=c("CURRENT.WEEK.DEATHS", "PREVIOUS.WEEKS.DEATHS")),
                   week_date = as.Date(paste(WEEK.NUMBER,1,sep="-"), format="%Y-%W-%w"))
```

Below demonstrates with random data, seeded for reproducibility, where *data4* is attempting to replicate your melted data, spanning the last weeks of 2016 and 2017.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

set.seed(306)
data4 <- data.frame(WEEK.NUMBER = as.vector(outer(2016:2017, 40:52, 
                                                  function(x,y) paste(x, y, sep="-"))),
                    variable = c(rep("CURRENT.WEEK.DEATHS", 26), 
                                 rep("PREVIOUS.WEEK.DEATHS", 26)),
                    value = sample(0:5, 52, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# NEW DATE VARIABLE
data4$week_date <- as.Date(paste(data4$WEEK.NUMBER, 1, sep="-"), format="%Y-%W-%w")

ggplot(data4, aes(fill=variable, y=value, x=week_date), color="black") + 
  geom_bar( stat="identity") +
  labs(x = "Week of Death", y="Number of Deaths") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = '', guide = 'legend',
                    labels = c('Death Reported Previous Week', 'Death Reported Current Week'),
                    values = c( "#00ffff","#009933")) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("1 weeks"), labels = date_format("%Y-%W"))+
  theme(legend.position='bottom') + 
  theme( axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1, size =5))
```

[image: GGPlot Output]

Comment: Thanks for the amazingly accurate answer. Much appreciate the time and effort!!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Happy coding!